# Best set of variables in linear regression when the response is repeated

Tags: regression, model-selection, predictor

I have monthly data about customer care in a bank branch. The variables are presented as follows:

**Global evaluation**: expressed in percentages.

**X1, X2, ... X14** : Yes or no questions taken from a survey passed to the clients.

The data have the following structure:

For each month there is a unique global evaluation, but there is approximately 100 observations in the variables X1, X2, ..., X14.

I need to know what is the best set of variables X1, X2, ... , X14 that explain the response variable. ¿ Is it correct to apply linear regression to this problem?

**Note**: The global evaluation is assigned independently of the values of the variables X1, X2, ..., X14. Finally, there is only 7 months.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the *best* way is but you could apply a linear kernel in each dimension (so the overall kernel is simply the product if these) with Gaussian noise. You then actually have a Gaussian over the gradients in each dimension and can determine the set of $k$ features which are most likely to contain the largest gradients - ie their values influence the outcome the most. It's not totally indifferent to automatic relevance detection for linear kernels (I am only mentioning linear kernels because that's the type of model you mentioned in the question).

This is just how I would naturally go about the problem but not necessarily the best way.